# I have define a class and instantiate it and after that I am calling methods of this class but it is not giving any output?

Tags: php

> code is here: $obj is the instance of class user.I am calling methods it is not showing the output

```
<?php
class user{
public  $name;
public  $age;
public function _ _construct($name, $age){
    $this->name=$name;
$this->age=$age;
}
public function sayHello(){
    echo("hiiiii".$this->name."!!!");
}
public function sayAge(){
    $a=time()-strtotime($this->age);
    echo  " hello Your age is".floor($a/(365*30*60*60));
}
}

$obj = new user('xyz','16 july 1980');
$obj->sayHello();
$obj->sayAge();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `$var` from `$obj.` Call it as just `$obj`

```
<?php
class user{
public  $name;
public  $age;
public function __construct($name, $age){
    $this->name=$name;
$this->age=$age;
}
public function sayHello(){
    echo("hiiiii".$this->name."!!!");
}
public function sayAge(){
    $a=time()-strtotime($this->age);
    echo  " hello Your age is".floor($a/(365*30*60*60));
}
}

$obj = new user('xyz','16 july 1980');
$obj->sayHello();
$obj->sayAge();

?>
```

Comment: @Ashiya, Just copy the code i pasted above and test. From your code your `constructor` is having a space between. Check that too.

Answer (score 1):

your contruct method is wrong

```
public function _ _construct($name, $age){
    $this->name=$name;
$this->age=$age;
}
```

remove the space and it should work

also remove the var from `$obj`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a syntax error on this line, and it's likely you aren't showing debugging/error messages in your PHP configuration so it looks like nothing is showing up:

```
var $obj = new user('xyz','16 july 1980');
```

"var" in front of that variable is not valid PHP syntax.